# Python/mechanize проблема с заполнением формы

Tags: python

Есть два select-a
Второй имеет свойство display:none и появляется только при выборе первого. 
Первый я выбираю без проблем:

```
br = Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.find_control(name='category_id').value = ["84"]
```

второй контрол:

```
br.find_control(name="param").value = ["1"]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    br.find_control(name="param").value = ["1"]
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'param'
```

Как задать значение второго селекта?

Comment: А 'param' там точно есть?

Comment: да.он "обернут" в 
<div class="class_name" id="params" style="display: none">
и появляется только тогда, когда выбирается значение первого селекта.
'param' - это имя появившегося селекта, которое можно видеть с помощью "просмотр кода элемента" в хроме

Comment: И откуда он там берётся, в этом хроме? Если он создаётся жаба-скриптом, в Вашей механике его найти будет проблемно, ибо я сомневаюсь, что механизаторы на sourceforge в своих механизмах ещё и js выполняют